# javascript forEach in LazyLoad not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have been using the script LazyLoad.js to load the images of my website dynamically. With Firefox it works without problem. But in IE it tells me that the forEach expression is not supported:
Here is the code:

```
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
                entries.forEach(function (entry) {
```

How can I replace this expression to make it also IE compatible?

Comment: It looks like [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver#Browser_compatibility) in IE is not supported, `forEach` works fine in IE>8.

Comment: Thanks, but the error I got in IE11 was about forEach not about the IntersectionObserver

Comment: So, you've a polyfill for `IntersectionObserver`? Then you should check the document mode you're running the page, should be > 8. Also, `forEach` is not an expression, it is a method of arrays (in IE) and in some objects.

Comment: The message says the object does not support forEach in IE11, is it possible to replace the forEach with something else? Should I use a normal for loop?

Comment: Hod do I check the "document mode" in IE?

Comment: As said before, IE doesn't support IntersectionObserver, who knows how the used polyfill is built, you could try a `for` loop. To check the document mode, just open the Dev Tools, on the right on the black bar there's a drop-down, select the latest version available from the list (the first).